# Angular checkbox stay checked after confirmation cancel

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a checkbox on an Angular project which executes a function when the user acts on it.
This function starts an "cancel" or "confirm" validation, if the user confirms then the checkbox takes the modification (if it was checked then it becomes unchecked and vice versa), otherwise if the user cancels the display of the checkbox must remain unchanged.

My problem is that when I click on the checkbox its state changes and if the user clicks on "Cancel" on confirmation I have to do f5 to return it to its original state.

**My checkbox**

```
<input id="contributorCheckbox"
     type="checkbox"
     [checked]="row.contributor"
     (click)="setRightContributor(row, $event.target.checked)">
```

**My function**

```
  setRightContributor(user: UserAccountDto, isChecked: boolean): void {
    this.matDialog.open(PopupConfirmationComponent, {
      data: {
        message: this.translateService.instant('GENERAL.CONFIRMATION_CONTRIBUTOR'),
      },
    }).afterClosed()
      .subscribe(confirmation => {
        if (confirmation) {
          user.contributor = isChecked;
          this.userAccountService.setRoleContributor(user, isChecked).subscribe();
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: When cancel is clicked on dialog then what do you want ?

Comment: @GRD I would like my checkbox to return to normal. For example, if it was not checked when I click on it it becomes checked, my popup opens and if I click on cancel I want it to not be checked again.

Comment: how many checkboxes do you have ?

Comment: @GRD I am using the mat-table element of the material angular library. There is one checkbox per line, it depends on the number of users that i've in my database.

Comment: This is exactly it, thank you very much

Comment: Can You please support and reward me back at this https://www.buymeacoffee.com/grdtech . I am also looking for work and also available to work on tasks. Thank You again. my email id is `grdtechlab@gmail.com`